# Rust download and save ZIP file

Tags: rust, zip, reqwest

I'm trying to download and save a Zip file. It seems like the download is working, but the saving goes wrong. If I try to unzip the file, I get the following error:

```
Archive:  download.zip
error [download.zip]:  missing 3208647056 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [download.zip]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Here's the code I'm using:

**cargo.toml**

```
# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.10"}
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
error-chain = "0.12.2"
```

**src/main.rs**

```rust
use error_chain::error_chain;
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

error_chain! {
     foreign_links {
         Io(std::io::Error);
         HttpRequest(reqwest::Error);
     }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let target = "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.0.0.zip";
    let response = reqwest::get(target).await?;

    let path = Path::new("./download.zip");

    let mut file = match File::create(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't create {}", why),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };
    let content =  response.text().await?;
    file.write_all(content.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Also note that nothing will actually execute asynchronously here, as the `std` types are all blocking.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I don't know why I didn't see this! It's working now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`reqwest::Response::text`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.6/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text) will try to parse the body of your request and replace any invalid UTF-8 sequence with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. For binary files, this will result in a corrupted file.

Instead you need to use [`reqwest::Response::bytes`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.6/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes) which returns the content as-is.